# How do I discover which program was launched?

Tags: c#, windows

Example: When searching for remote desktop in windows help, it has a link to "Click to open System.". (Not telling me *how* to open System) Is there some place in the computer with the locations of programs that are opened so that I can click on the abovementioned link, and then check that location to see what was opened? If not, is there some method for that (say, in .net)? Or perhaps an app that does that (preferably by Microsoft).

EDIT: I need enough information about the program in order to launch it from my program (`Process.Start(...);`).

Comment: Huh? You will have to explain a little better.

Comment: @leppie I want to find what program was just now launched.

Comment: If you want to find the path to binaries of running processes using c# you should look into the [System.Diagnostics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg145030.aspx) namespace.

Comment: @Filburt Thanks. I'm looking into it. When I find a process, Is there a way to find where is the file that launched it (so that I can launch it myself)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for application like Process Explorer http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653

Comment: Yep, or Process Monitor if you need to log process activity over time

Comment: Thanks. This or Process Monitor (Thanks @Ian) is probably what I'm looking for. Do you know how to sort the processes in them? (I need the newest on top.)

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for task manager? <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd>

If you are looking for specific places in the system that you can open via explorer or a gui then there will most likely be an exe somewhere for it.

For example opening `System` as per your question would be found here:

```
C:\Windows\winsxs\amd64_microsoft-windows-s..mpropertiesadvanced_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7600.16385_none_533d797efdf7728b\SystemPropertiesAdvanced.exe
```

Once it is open you can see the SystemPropertiesAdvanced.exe process in task manager. You can also right click on the process and Open File Location giving you the location of the file that it launched from.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. But for some reason I can't seem to find my example's process there. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: It will be there, but it might be threaded under a different process like svchost.exe or csrss in which case you would find it with Process Explorer like Sarrus suggested.

Comment: @ispiro Updated answer with some more info.